# publishing issue mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012

I am trying to deploy a asp.net mvc application via visual studio 2012. I am getting this exception:

[image]

Any ideas?

PS:

.pubxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>False</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>DonotMerge</WDPMergeOption>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <publishUrl>\\somwhere\bladibla\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Could you post your .pubxml file? Perhaps the target directory is not set correctly.

Comment: thanks. see ps - cannot see anything amiss ...

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451356/vs2012-2013-cant-publish-services-project-specified-path-is-too-long . Seems that it has to do with special characters in your publish name.

Comment: Thanks - that was it. post an answer if u like ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with special characters in the name of the publish settings. Have a look at: [VS2012 & 2013: Can't publish Services project - specified path is too long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22451356/vs2012-2013-cant-publish-services-project-specified-path-is-too-long)